# is there any way to loop through $this->input->post() array in CodeIgnitor?

Tags: codeigniter

i have following html in CodeIgnitor view

```
foreach ($data as $r)
{
 echo "<td>".$r->memberid."</td>";
 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='memberid' name='id".$i."' value='".$r->memberid."'></td>";
 echo "<td>".$r->name."</td>";
}
```

i want to submit multiple check boxes that are generated through loop . on clicking submit button when $this->input->post() array is passed to controller but here checkbox name is generated with variable. is there any way to echo $this->input->post('id'$i) array in controller through array??

Comment: i want to loop through $this->input->post() array in codeIgnitor

Comment: hey what is `$i` & `name is same` in all checkbox.

Comment: @KUMAR in loop it will be id1

Comment: so what you want explain with picture.

Comment: @KUMAR it will generate  [ id1 , id2, id3,  id4 ] till loop end now how to access these $_POST[$id1] $_POST[$id2] $_POST[$id3] $_POST[$id4]